# Generated Update sql for child entity is incorrect in One-to-many relation 

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes, ElwInfo and ElwUnderlyingAsset in parent-child relationship. Table names are ELW_INFO, ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET and ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET refers to ELW_INFO by column INSTRUMENT_CD.

I've mapped both classes in file 'Elw.hbm.xml' as follows

```
<class name="ElwInfo" table="ELW_INFO" >

    <id name="instrumentCode" column="INSTRUMENT_CD" ><generator class="assigned"/></id>
    <property name="instrumentName" column="INSTRUMENT_NM"/>
    <property name="ccyCode"        column="CCY_CD"/>

    <one-to-one name="instrumentCommon" 
                class="InstrumentCommon"
                cascade="save-update" lazy="false" />

    <one-to-one name="instrumentClass" 
                class="InstrumentClass"
                cascade="none" lazy="false" />

    <property name="issueDate"      column="ISSUE_DT"/>
    <property name="maturityDate"   column="MRTY_DT"/>
    <property name="convertRatio"   column="CONVERT_RATIO"/>
    <property name="strike"         column="STRIKE"/>
    <property name="koBarrier"      column="KO_BARRIER"/>
    <property name="minRebateRate"  column="MIN_REBATE_RT"/>
    <property name="addRebate"      column="ADD_REBATE"/>

    <many-to-one class="com.fistglobal.riskcraft.market.web.domain.instrument2.common.ExchangeInfo" 
                 name="exchangeInfo" column="EXCH_CD" lazy="false" cascade="none" 
                 unique="true" />
    <many-to-one class="com.fistglobal.riskcraft.market.web.domain.instrument2.common.ElwTypeInfo" 
                 name="elwType" column="ELW_TYPE_CD" lazy="false" cascade="none" 
                 unique="true" />
    <many-to-one class="com.fistglobal.riskcraft.market.web.domain.instrument2.common.OptionTypeInfo" 
                 name="optionType" column="OPTION_TYPE_CD" lazy="false" cascade="none" 
                 unique="true" />
    <many-to-one class="com.fistglobal.riskcraft.market.web.domain.instrument2.common.ExerciseTypeInfo" 
                 name="exerciseType" column="EXERCISE_TYPE_CD" lazy="false" cascade="none" 
                 unique="true" />

    **<bag name="underlyingAssetList" cascade="save-update" table="ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET" lazy="false" >
        <key column="INSTRUMENT_CD"/>
        <one-to-many class="ElwUnderlyingAsset" not-found="ignore"/>
    </bag>**

</class>

<class name="ElwUnderlyingAsset" table="ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET" >
    <composite-id name="id" class="ElwUnderlyingAsset$Id">
        <key-property name="instrumentCode" column="INSTRUMENT_CD"/>
        <key-property name="underlyingAssetCode" column="UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD"/>
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="qty"   column="UNDERLYING_ASSET_QTY"/>
</class>

<class name="ElwData" table="ELW_DATA">
    <composite-id name="key" class="InstrumentDataKey">
        <key-property name="dt"             column="DT"/>
        <key-property name="instrumentCode" column="INSTRUMENT_CD"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="barrierHitYn"   column="BARRIER_HIT_YN"/>
    <property name="barrierHitDate" column="BARRIER_HIT_DT"/>
    <property name="amOrPm"         column="AM_OR_PM"/>
    <property name="maxPrice"       column="MAX_PRICE"/>
    <property name="minPrice"       column="MIN_PRICE"/>
</class>
```

and the two class is as follows

```
public class ElwInfo extends InstrumentInfo {

private ExchangeInfo exchangeInfo;
private List<ElwUnderlyingAsset> underlyingAssetList;
private ElwTypeInfo elwType;
private OptionTypeInfo optionType;
private ExerciseTypeInfo exerciseType;

private String issueDate;
private String maturityDate;
private Double convertRatio;
private Double strike;
private Double koBarrier;
private Double minRebateRate;
private Double addRebate;

public ElwInfo() {
    exchangeInfo = new ExchangeInfo();
    underlyingAssetList = new ArrayList<ElwUnderlyingAsset>();
    elwType = new ElwTypeInfo();
    optionType = new OptionTypeInfo();
    exerciseType = new ExerciseTypeInfo();
}

public ExchangeInfo getExchangeInfo() {
    return exchangeInfo;
}

public void setExchangeInfo(ExchangeInfo exchangeInfo) {
    this.exchangeInfo = exchangeInfo;
}

public List<ElwUnderlyingAsset> getUnderlyingAssetList() {
    return underlyingAssetList;
}

public void setUnderlyingAssetList(List<ElwUnderlyingAsset> underlyingAssetList) {
    this.underlyingAssetList = underlyingAssetList;
}

public ElwTypeInfo getElwType() {
    return elwType;
}

public void setElwType(ElwTypeInfo elwType) {
    this.elwType = elwType;
}

public OptionTypeInfo getOptionType() {
    return optionType;
}

public void setOptionType(OptionTypeInfo optionType) {
    this.optionType = optionType;
}

public ExerciseTypeInfo getExerciseType() {
    return exerciseType;
}

public void setExerciseType(ExerciseTypeInfo execType) {
    this.exerciseType = execType;
}

public String getIssueDate() {
    return issueDate;
}

public void setIssueDate(String issueDate) {
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
}

public String getMaturityDate() {
    return maturityDate;
}

public void setMaturityDate(String maturityDate) {
    this.maturityDate = maturityDate;
}

public Double getConvertRatio() {
    return convertRatio;
}

public void setConvertRatio(Double convertRatio) {
    this.convertRatio = convertRatio;
}

public Double getStrike() {
    return strike;
}

public void setStrike(Double strike) {
    this.strike = strike;
}

public Double getKoBarrier() {
    return koBarrier;
}

public void setKoBarrier(Double koBarrier) {
    this.koBarrier = koBarrier;
}

public Double getMinRebateRate() {
    return minRebateRate;
}

public void setMinRebateRate(Double minRebateRate) {
    this.minRebateRate = minRebateRate;
}

public Double getAddRebate() {
    return addRebate;
}

public void setAddRebate(Double addRebate) {
    this.addRebate = addRebate;
}

}


public class ElwUnderlyingAsset {

public static class Id implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8296040137055492597L;

    private String instrumentCode;
    private String underlyingAssetCode;

    public String getInstrumentCode() {
        return instrumentCode;
    }
    public void setInstrumentCode(String instrumentCode) {
        this.instrumentCode = instrumentCode;
    }
    public String getUnderlyingAssetCode() {
        return underlyingAssetCode;
    }
    public void setUnderlyingAssetCode(String underlyingAssetCode) {
        this.underlyingAssetCode = underlyingAssetCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Id) {
            Id that = (Id)o;
            return this.instrumentCode.equals(that.instrumentCode) && this.underlyingAssetCode.equals(that.underlyingAssetCode);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        if (instrumentCode!= null && underlyingAssetCode != null)
            return instrumentCode.hashCode() + underlyingAssetCode.hashCode();
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }

}

public ElwUnderlyingAsset() {
    this.id = new Id();
}

private Id id;
private Double qty;

public Id getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Id id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getQty() {
    return qty;
}
public void setQty(Double qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
}
}
```

when I call

```
ElwInfo newInfo = .....// info instance is constructed purely from http request parameters .
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(newInfo);
```

I get the following Generated SQL and Oracle Native Exception. The generated SQL is quite absurd and I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

```
Hibernate: 
update
    ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET 
set
    INSTRUMENT_CD=null 
where
    INSTRUMENT_CD=?
```

What I expect is

```
Hibernate: 
update
    ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET 
set
    QTY = ?
where
    INSTRUMENT_CD=?
    and UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD=?
```

because table ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET has composite key (INSTRUMENT_CD, UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD).

If I modify my client code as follows,

```
ElwInfo newInfo = .....// info instance is constructed purely from http request 
ElwInfo info = (ElwInfo)getHibernateTemplate().get(entityInfo.getClass(),entityInfo.getInstrumentCode());
info.setAddRebate(0.0);
info.getUnderlyingAssetList().clear();
info.getUnderlyingAssetList().addAll(newInfo.getUnderlyingAssetList());
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(info);
```

I get the following generated SQL;

```
Hibernate: 
update
    ELW_INFO 
set
    INSTRUMENT_NM=?,
    CCY_CD=?,
    ISSUE_DT=?,
    MRTY_DT=?,
    CONVERT_RATIO=?,
    STRIKE=?,
    KO_BARRIER=?,
    MIN_REBATE_RT=?,
    ADD_REBATE=?,
    EXCH_CD=?,
    ELW_TYPE_CD=?,
    OPTION_TYPE_CD=?,
    EXERCISE_TYPE_CD=? 
where
    INSTRUMENT_CD=?

Hibernate: 
update
    ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET 
set
    INSTRUMENT_CD=null 
where
    INSTRUMENT_CD=? 
    and UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD=?
```

The first generated sql is ok, but the second one is still wrong though it differs a bit from the previous one.

Thank you for your troubles in advance.

Comment: 1. How you map entity with composite id on only one column ?

Comment: 2. Do you set INSTRUMENT_CD, when creates ElwInfo?

Comment: Table ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET has composite key (INSTRUMENT_CD, UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD) and I mapped those columns to composite-id. and I surely confirmed set instrumentCode property on ElwInfo instance and it's collection's ElwUnderlyingAsset instances.

Comment: no, you map bag only with column INSTRUMENT_CD, as i see in mapping.
You shoul use something like <key><column name="INSTRUMENT_CD"/><column name="UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD"/></key>

Comment: The key column 'INSTRUMENT_CD' in bag mapping means ELW_INFO table's INSTRUMENT_CD column is used for the selection of ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET table's records. How can you map UDERLYING_ASSET_CD column in the bag because the column is in ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET, **not in ELW_INFO**. More over, I tested your mapping just in case and I've got Error 'Foreign key (FKA079D73DCDF8DCD1:ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET [INSTRUMENT_CD,UNDERLYING_ASSET_CD])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ELW_INFO [INSTRUMENT_CD])'

Answer (score 0):

I've added attribute **inverse="true"** in the bag mapping, and no more errors occurred.

```
<bag name="underlyingAssetList" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" table="ELW_UNDERLYING_ASSET" lazy="false" >
        <key column="INSTRUMENT_CD"/>
        <one-to-many class="ElwUnderlyingAsset" not-found="ignore"/>
</bag>
```

I'm quoting the following from the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate, p266".

> Without the inverse attribute, Hibernate tries to execute two
>   different SQL statements,  both updating the same foreign key column,
>   when you manipulate the link between two instances. By specifying
>   inverse="true", you explicitly tell  Hibernate which end of the link
>   it should not synchronize with the database.  In this example, you
>   tell Hibernate that it should propagate changes made at the
>   (ElwUnderlyingAsset) end of the association to the database, ignoring
>   changes made only to the (underlyingAssetList) collection.